# Локализация JFileChooser через UIManager. Где найти ключи локализации?

Tags: java, swing, ui

Пытаю локализовать `JFileChooser` через `UIManager`. Делаю это вот так:`

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.saveButtonText", "Сохранить");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonText", "Отмена");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileNameLabelText", "Наименование файла");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelText", "Типы файлов");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.lookInLabelText", "Директория");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.saveInLabelText", "Сохранить в директории");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.folderNameLabelText", "Путь директории");
```

И далее, где то 20 строк.  Но не могу найти всех ключей к FileChooser. Кто-нибудь знает где они?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Список можно получить из из ресурсов Swing в зависимости от используемого Look&Fill.

Например: 
[basic](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/swing/internal/plaf/basic/resources/basic.java)

В пакете com.sun.java.swing.plaf есть пакеты под различные локали различных look&fill. Открыв их можно собрать все ресурсы начинающиеся с FileChooser.

Кроме того там есть ресурсы и для прочих стандартных диалогов.

Comment: Я использую com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel . Я его не могу найти на этом сайте. Или это и есть basic?

Comment: @RodGers не обязательно искать на сайте, можно открыт класс в используемой вами IDE. Кроме того, если я правильно понимаю как это  работает, сначала будет загружаться com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.basic.resources.basic, а после него какие-либо ресурсы могут быть заменены используемым look&fill. Исходя из этого предположения в com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.basic.resources.basic должны быть все ресурсы необходимые стандартным диалогам. А значит достаточно переопределить их для локализации диалога.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Нашёл.